# What is $\mathrm{U(1)}$ vector and axial?

Tags: terminology, group-theory, notation

In hadron physics we talked about $\mathrm{U(1)_V}$ (vector) and $\mathrm{U(1)_A}$ (axial) as well as $\mathrm{SU(3)_L}$ (left) and $\mathrm{SU(3)_R}$ (right). There are certain relations between them which were shown in the chapter of spontaneous symmetry breaking.

What are those groups? Are they any different than the $\mathrm{U(1)}$ and $\mathrm{SU(3)}$ that I know from group theory?

Comment: They are, abstractly, just the $\mathrm{U}(1)$ and $\mathrm{SU}(3)$ groups. The subscripts don't denote a different groups, but denote how *this particular copy of $\mathrm{U}(1)$ acts*